# Installation Optimisation With Limited SSD Space

Tags: windows-7, installation, performance, ssd, optimize

Tomorrow, I need to rebuild a windows 7 machine due to various issues. It currently has a 500GB HDD as the primary drive, with a 120GB SSD.

As a developer, I need to keep as much space free as I can on the SSD for several (large) code branches. However, I'd like to install windows into the SSD to gain the performance boosts.

I'm aware of the obvious tricks to free up space, such as:

- Disabling Hibernation
- Moving the page file onto another drive
- Installing non-performance critical apps into the HDD
- Moving user folders onto the HDD

Are there any other tricks that can minimise the usage of the SSD space?

I'm particularly concerned with Windows growing and growing over time (mostly due to the patches folder I believe) - given that this is a fresh install, are there any tricks that can be used to have windows move non-critical files onto another drive, etc?

Answer (score -1):

Well its tricky but it can work. You can use the **[MKLink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx)** Command.

MKLink Creates Links from a Location to Another. You can basically move a "NON-Critical" Folder or even some Default Installed Windows Programms to your HDD and Link these folders from your SSD to HDD.

So basically your System will think that they will be on C:/ but they will be on D:/ or whatever letter is your secondary drive.

You can read more about MKLink Directory Junctions over [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html)